# Implementing sweet alert for delete button in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to implement a kind of sweet alert on the delete button in my project. in the tag `a`I put

`onClick = {() => {props.deleteHandle(props.data.code)}}`

code is my variable.

I use this function as props.

i defined as the following:

```
deleteHandle = (code) => {
    let self = this;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delet this item?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover your data!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, async () => {
        let url = `/api/v1/wiki/admin/delete?wCode=${code}`;
        if (self.state.type === "faqs") {
            url = `/api/v1/faq/admin/delete?fCode=${code}`
        }
        if (self.state.type === "chapters") {
            url = `/api/v1/ch/admin/delete?chCode=${code}`
        }
        await baseUrl.get(url, {
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
            },
        });
        self.fetchData(self.state.type);
    });
}
```

i installed swal by `npm install sweetalert --save`
And also i imported the swal library as bellow:
`import swal from 'sweetalert';`

However, the delete button doesn't work. but I removed swal from the function it works.
I tried to figure out my problem, but I can not understand.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get some errors?

Comment: Yes, still not working, i removed the second argument of swal alert is shown, then i put the second argument async ()=> .... , then it doesn't work, also i removed the swal delete button works with out sweet alert.

Comment: here is the error message:

Uncaught SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument (async () => {
 let url = `/api/v1/wiki/admin/delete?wikiCode=${code}`;

 if (self.state.type === "faqs") {
 url = `/api/v1/faq/admin/delete?faqCode=${code}`;
 }

 if (self.state.type === "chapters") {
 url = `/api/v1/ch/admin/delete?chapterCode=${code}`;
 }

 await _utils_hbes__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__["default"].get(url, {
 headers: {
 "content-type": "application/json",
 Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
 }
 });
 self.fetchData(self.state.type);
 })

Comment: The error tells you that the second argument is unexpected.

Comment: I moved it to out of swal ({....}).then () but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the error the same? What arguments do you pass? Can you check this in the browser dev tools at the bottom of the call stack?

Comment: it shown me sweet alert then i hit ok the alert but request is failed and code is 404 and error is as following:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: The error has changed then. So you either passed the old error and found a new one or a new error has creeped into your project in the meantime.

Comment: The previous error has disappearde. but since i shifted the arqument async () etc out of swal argument sweet alert works but it seems that after .then(....), request is not done.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, there was typos some where. i solved it

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the second argument of swal and I put it inside promise .then ( async => {...}).